# Why is the water column empty in ICE table

Tags: homework, equilibrium, aqueous-solution, solutions

In the ICE table pure solids and liquids have a value of one in the equilibrium expression but when we create an ICE table, why is the $\ce{H_{2}O}$ column empty? Should it not have a value of one?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably water is the solvent for this reaction, which means that it will be in extreme excess and the amount will not change to a measurable extent.